# What does GROUP in an udev rule actually set?

Tags: udev

I have a new Brother MFC and had permission issues and managed to solve them by changing `GROUP="scanner"` to `GROUP="lp"` in the relevant udev rule as my user is in the `lp` group but not in the `scanner` group and I didn't want to log out and in. However `/dev/usb/lp0` was lp before and it still is. So it must be something else, but what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably changed the rule pertaining to the `/dev/bus/usb/<busnum>/<devnum>` device nodes. Those are generic USB device nodes, which can be used from user-space programs to communicate with any USB device (even those that do not have any specific driver).